# How to play a video using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to play a video using `opencv` (the video is an avi file stored on the disk). However, the program stops execution on the following line in `cap_ffmppeg.cpp`:

```
if(!ffmpegCapture ||
   !icvRetrieveFrame_FFMPEG_p(ffmpegCapture,&data,&step,&width,&height,&cn))
   return 0;
```

The error is: `Access violation reading location`... so a seg fault is occurring the first time `capture >> frame` is run.

Here is the program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.h>
#include<opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s video\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    VideoCapture capture(argv[1]);


    if(!capture.isOpened())
    {
        printf("Failed to open the video\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        capture >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `cv::VideoCapture` expects a string in the constructur, but you are using a character array. I am not sure if this works.

Also have you tried an absolute path to your file?

Comment: changed it to `VideoCapture capture("C:\\video.avi");` but the problem persists...

Comment: Ok, also if the `isOpened` check is passed acessing the file shouldn't be the problem. Have you tried a different file?

Comment: some progress made... different file produces the following: `OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /tmp/SBo/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/SBo/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat`

Comment: could it be that i'm trying unsupported video formats?

Comment: That's what I'd suspect, your code looks fine otherwise. You can could confirm that by opening a webcam if you have one: `VideoCapture capture(0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that OpenCV couldn't play the uncompressed video. Compressed it and all is well... don't know why the original problem exists tho.

Answer (score 1):

if your using x64. 
Please use opencv_ffmpeg245_64.dll this solves may solve the problem.
Or rename opencv_ffmpeg245_64.dll to  opencv_ffmpeg245 may solve the problem.